# Lambda expression to Func<T, TResult>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, func

How can I write the lambda expression in `optionObject.Forms.First(f => f.FormId == formId).MultipleIteration` to a Func so at the end I have something like

```
Func<FormObject, bool> FormID = f => f.formID == passedVal;
```

and then use it on the first expression to get something like

```
optionObject.Forms.First(FormID).MultipleIteration
```

I tried

```
Func<FormObject, PassedVal, bool> FormID => formID == PassedVal;
```

but did not work. 
**Please note that** there is nothing wrong with the lambda expression, it works fine. I am just trying to create a function to replace the expression with the name of the function to make the code look shorter and maintainable.

Comment: not following, can you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reuse of a LINQ query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337294/reuse-of-a-linq-query)

Comment: Yes, this is just like Reuse of a LINQ link above, just that in this case the value to compare with is not hard coded, but a parameter passed to the method where the expression is used

Comment: The reason your `Func<FormObject, PassedVal, bool>` didn't work is that the signature of the lambda taken by `First` and similar methods would need to be `Func<FormObject, bool>`. Since you have another value that you also want to parameterize, 31eee384's answer looks like the best and possibly the only way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that lets you reuse the function body with new passed values is to generate `Func<FormData, bool>` instances in a class-level function:

```
public static Func<FormObject, bool> CreateFormValidFunc(int validId)
{
    return f => f.formID == validId;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
optionObject.Forms.First(CreateFormValidFunc(passedVal)).MultipleIteration
optionObject.Forms.First(CreateFormValidFunc(2)).MultipleIteration
```

---

An interesting side note is that `int Foo => 0;` is "expression-bodied properties" syntax ([new to C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), and your attempt might have matched it just enough to make the error messages confusing.

You can use expression-bodied methods to reduce the validation func generator to:

```
public static Func<FormObject, bool> CreateFormValidFunc(int validId) => f => f.formID == validId;
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This post can help you:
[lambda expression and var keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897611/lambda-expression-and-var-keyword-in-c-sharp)

> When I try to use `var add = (x, y) => x + y;` the compiler need to be able to reduce the set to just one type for x and one for y (not exactly true, it might be that both a base class and a derived class would fit) and still even if the compiler could figure out the type for x and y or that you specified the types to let's say int you'd still be left with the fact that both  Expression> and Func are possible types for add.

In your scenario you can use this:

```
Expression<Func<FormObject, bool>> FormID = f => f.formID == passedVal;
```