# Operator 'op ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'dynamic' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, dynamic

I can't seem to apply binary operations to lambda expressions, delegates and method groups.

```
dynamic MyObject = new MyDynamicClass();
MyObject >>= () => 1 + 1;
```

The second line gives me error: `Operator '>>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'dynamic' and 'lambda expression'`

Why?

Isn't the operator functionality determined by my custom `TryBinaryOperation` override?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not an issue with `MyDynamicClass`, the problem is that you can't have a lambda expression as a dynamic. This however, does appear to work:

```
dynamic MyObject = new MyDynamicClass();
Func<int> fun = () => 1 + 1;
var result = MyObject >>= fun;
```

If the `TryBinaryOperation` looks like this:

```
result = ((Func<int>) arg)();
return true;
```

Then `result` will be 2. You can use `binder.Operation` to determine which binary operation this is.

Comment: This is interesting and surprising; I'm on mobile at the moment, but I must look at this later!

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I think the restriction that the second operand must be an int is enforced only when you define the operator, and not when you use it.

Comment: @ShdNx - the odd thing is you could return a string if you wanted to.

Comment: `the problem is that you can't have a lambda expression as a dynamic` Is there an explanation for that?

Comment: @Conrad: Likely for the [same reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965576/c-why-cant-an-anonymous-method-be-assigned-to-var) you can't declare a lambda as var. It's *possible*, but the functionality isn't there.

Comment: @Conrad - there would be no default delegate-type or `T` in `Expression<T>` - you'd need the compiler to assume (for example) `Action<...>`/`Func<...>` - possible, but not necessarily desirable.

Comment: This intrigued me - you are absolutely right that this is possible; wrote up my example here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/08/shifting-expectations-non-integer-shift.html

Answer (score 2):

```
dynamic MyObject = new MyDynamicClass();
MyObject >>= new Func<int>(() => 1 + 1);
```