# Why can't an anonymous class have a lambda property, but it can have a Func<> property?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C#'s restrictions on an anonymous type. Consider the following code:

```
  var myAwesomeObject = new {
      fn1 = new Func<int>(() => { return 5; }),
      fn2 = () => { return 5; } 
  };
```

So we've got two properties that are actually functions:

- `fn1`: A `Func<int>` that returns `5`.
- `fn2`: A lambda function that returns `5`.

The C# compiler is happy to work with fn1, but complains about fn2 :

> cannot assign lambda expression to anonymous type property.

Can someone explain why one is ok but the other is not?

Comment: The compiler won't find a type that matches the anonymous method. It will coerce or use a type, if you use the anonymous method in a context where such a type can be determined, like in a method call, but in this case it won't pick a matching type. You have the same problem if you go: `var fn2 = () => { return 5; };`

Comment: The C# compiler doesn’t know if the lambda is meant to be a delegate or an expression tree. The solution is to instantiate the one you want to create.

Comment: @Thomas is right, but here's a more complete answer from Eric Lippert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965576/c-sharp-why-cant-an-anonymous-method-be-assigned-to-var/4966409#4966409

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because there is no way for the compiler to know the type of `() => { return 5; }`; it could be a `Func<int>`, but it could also be any other delegate with the same signature (it could also be an expression tree). That's why you have to specify the type explicitly.

Comment: Ah... So it's a type inference problem. What's your recommendation for the most elegant code in this example? Is there anything I can do to refine the fn1 definition?

Comment: @StephenGross, well, you can also cast the lambda to the delegate type: `fn1 = (Func<int>)(() => { return 5; })`; but I prefer the explicit delegate creation, like you did in your question.

Comment: Even more, it might not be a delegate at all; it could be an `Expression<Func<int>>`!