# A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq code

```
var advertisements = _applicationContext.Advertisings.ToList();

var stepsData = advertisements.Select(a => new[]
{
    new
    {
        number = a.Number,
        text = a.Text,
        image = a.Image,
        type = a.Type,
        data = (a) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Link) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Deeplink))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new
            {
                link = a.Link,
                deeplink = a.Deeplink
            };
        }
    }
});
```

See on the `data` property. A value of this property depends on values `Link` and `DeepLink` of item `a`. The `a` is an instance of the following model:

```
public class Advertising
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public bool Show { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    public string Deeplink { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public Advertising()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

All is good, but I see a notification from IDE 
`A local or parameter named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter`

How to use lambda in this case? I need to pass into the lambda variable `a`. Without params, it shows me the following error
`Cannot assign 'lambda expression' to anonymous type property`

### Update

Lambda without params gives me the following result

[image]

Error text:
`Cannot assign 'lambda expression' to anonymous type property`

Comment: **1.** You're re-using `a` (which is already defined in this scope) for `data = (a) => { ... }`. **2.** How do you expect the compiler to infer the type of the `data` property of your anonymous type?

Comment: Just use a different name.... `data => b => {...}`

Comment: After changing name I see `Cannot assign 'lambda expression' to anonymous type property`

Comment: `a` is the argument of the enclosing anonymous lambda associated with the Select statement, then you use it again as the argument of the lambda associated with the data property. if you change `data=(a)=>` to `data =()=>` I believe you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: See this answer to explain why you're getting the other error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128625/why-cant-an-anonymous-class-have-a-lambda-property-but-it-can-have-a-func-pr

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak, Try to rewrite your assignment as `data = string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Link) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Deeplink) ? null : new { ... }`

Comment: @haim770 nice hack))) I will use it to avoid this problem just now)) Thank you))

Comment: Slighty off-topic, the `ToList()` call in the first line brings the whole DB into memory before doing anything is almost never a good idea and very likely to give bad performance.

Comment: If @haim770's answer works for you, that means you didn't need a lambda in the first place. You want `data` to reference either another anonymous type or null. As you had originally written it, you were setting `data` to equal a *function* that returned an anonymous type or null.

Comment: @Alejandro could you give me some proofs? Maybe some article. Where I can read about it?