# How to create Task on async delegate without a Func<> variable?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following code:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Func<Task<double>> f = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
};
Task<double> delayTask = f();
```

But I can't figure it out how to write it as a single statement without assigning the delegate to a variable first. That is, I feel like I should be able to just do something like

```
Task<double> delayTask = (async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
})();
```

or even

```
Task<double> delayTask = new Task<double>(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
});
```

but both give compilation errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
Task<double> delayTask = new Func<Task<double>>(async () => 
{  
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token); 
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds; 
})();
```

Comment: Yep, that just came to me a few minutes ago, tried it out and sure enough it does the job, though it still seem like more syntax that should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting errors for the same reason you can't compile this:

```
var f = async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
};
```

You must specify the required type somewhere for type inference to be able to work. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965576/885318).

You can however remove the need for a variable with a simple cast:

```
var delayTask = ((Func<Task<double>>) (async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
    return (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
}))();
```