# Trigger function(s) based upon Boolean result without using the iF word

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, ternary

```
if(someBoolTest()) dothis()
else dothat();
```

or just

```
if(someBoolTest()) dothis();
```

Wouldn't it be nice to do something like:

```
someBoolTest() => {dothis(),dothat()}
```

or

```
someBoolTest() => dothis()
```

Is this done in other languages?
How do we do this in C#? 
(I don't think we can, so then why not?)

EDIT:
I am aware of ternary ops, but that doesn't make it look any better.  Would be nice to do this with some form of lambda with delegates..

Comment: What advantage does your syntax have over `if` statements?

Comment: You need to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4966409/2589202)

Comment: I'm really unclear of the point of this question.  Is this just a rant on how you aren't happy that C# isn't a functional language?

Comment: yes, it is partially a rant.  but at the same time, it asks the question of why can't C# have this language extension..|
But I am happy with C#, it is what I use every day..

Answer (score 4):

> How do we do this in C#?

Using the `if-else` clause, just as you did in your example.

You *could* be creative and create something of this sort:

```
(SomeBoolTest() ? (Action)DoThis : DoThat)();
```

But that is terribly unreadable code, don't do that.

Comment: I'm sure functional languages have a different way of doing `if-else` branching. Still, I don't see anything wrong with them.

Comment: @LastTribunal What are dirty word?

Comment: @Black He's referring to `if-else`

Comment: I just wanted to be clear.  Because `if-else` is one of the basic building blocks of programming.  And the con with using `?: Operator` is that is doesn't do [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: If statements are the building blocks of spaghetti code.  All efforts in OOP and Design Patterns were basically intended to address the obscenity of "iF" words..

Comment: Can you actually articulate what you find offensive about the if-else construct?

Comment: @BlackFrog the conditional (`?:`) operator does short-circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You can, **but should not**, do something that resembles the syntax that you mentioned, by doing something stupid like writing an extension method over a `bool` type, as shown in the below example:

```
public static class UselessExtensions
{
    public static void WhenTrue(this bool evaluatedPredicate, Action whenTrue)
    {
        if (evaluatedPredicate)
            whenTrue();
    }
}

public static class TryingUselessExtensions
{
    public static bool SomeBoolTest()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static void DoIt()
    {
        SomeBoolTest().WhenTrue(() => Console.WriteLine(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: It defers ifs to a lower level, which is an improvement

Comment: @Claies As you can see, the answer specifically states "something that resembles the **syntax** ...", its purpose is not to get rid of the if statement.

Comment: true, but in other comments the poster has suggested the reason for the question in the first place is their dislike of `if-else`, referring to it as "these dirty words, will be removed from all evolved languages".  It isn't a sensible statement, but the poster has made it clear they want an alternative to `if-else`, not just syntax to hide it (unless I'm way off).

Answer (score 0):

I believe ternary operators are what you're looking for:

variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false

So, for example you want an int to equal 0 if your condition is met, and 3 if it is not:

```
int this = 500;
int that = 700;
int n = (this==that) ? 0 : 3;
```

In this case n would be assigned the value of 3! There's a good wikipedia page on this, head on over and give it a look :)

[Wikipedia page on ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: This approach is useful when you want a conditional expression to return a value and each operand is a function that returns a value. However, the question is about how to conditionally execute a pair of functions where neither returns a value.

Answer (score -1):

You do it like this

```
    bool myBool = true;
    bool newBool;
    public void Main()
    {
        MyFunction( newBool = (aFunctionThatReturnsABool == true) ? true: false);
    }

    public void MyFunction (bool aBool)
    {
        // stuff based on the bool
    }
```

But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: need to call methods, not set variables

Comment: `(aFunctionThatReturnsABool == true) ? true: false` is exactly equivalent to `aFunctionThatReturnsABool`, btw.