# What can I replace here since I can't have a lambda function with implicit variable in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to implement a tile-based platforming system for a 2D game demo from [this C++ code](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_PlatformGame1.cpp) into C#,

This is what I have written, It doesn't compile though due to the var variable usage.

```
 class GameLogic
{
    // Level storage
    String sLevel;
    int nLevelWidth;
    int nLevelHeight;

    // Player Properties
    float fPlayerPosX = 1.0f;
    float fPlayerPosY = 1.0f;
    float fPlayerVelX = 0.0f;
    float fPlayerVelY = 0.0f;
    bool bPlayerOnGround = false;

    // Camera properties
    float fCameraPosX = 0.0f;
    float fCameraPosY = 0.0f;

    public GameLogic()
    {
         var GetTile = (ref int x, ref int y) =>
        {
            if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
                return sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x];
            else
                return "";
        };

        var SetTile = (ref int x, ref int y, string c)=>                
        {
            if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
                sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x] = c;
        };

    }
}
```

What do you suggest I should do here, to implement this functionality. Thank you for your time.

Comment: why are you using "ref" here? do you expect GetTile to modify the coordinates?

Comment: The original code from the c++ link is using ref variables. I have yet to test it so I'm not sure if it's necessary as I'm still learning the code. @IMil

Comment: at a quick glance, you can implement GetTitle/SetTitle as ordinary methods without any magic incantations

Comment: You have an important misunderstanding about the meaning of "capture by reference" in C++ as it relates to C#. C# automatically captures outer locals "by reference" -- that is, it captures *variables* and not *values of variables*. Moreover, the variables captured are the *outer* variables, not the formal parameters of the lambda!  Make sure you understand this distinction before you proceed; it is important to get this right.

Comment: To expand upon @IMil's comment above: you can make `GetTile` and `SetTile` local functions in new versions of C#; again, the compiler will take care of ensuring that outer locals of local functions are captured appropriately.  C# does not have a facility for "capture by value" like C++ does. (There are rare cases where values are captured instead of variables but you are not likely to run into them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn´t compile because of the `var` statement.
When you use `LambdaExpressions` and you want to save it to a variable you have to define the `delegate` Type.
But you can´t use `ref` variables here. But that is ok, because you don´t change the value of `x` or `y`.

You need a Delegate that describes the type of your function.
You could build you own `delegate` type but in C# there are two built in types for that case.
`Action` & `Action<T1-16>` -> always returns `void`
`Func<T1-17>` you can define the return type

The `GetTile` function takes two `int` and returns a `string`.
So you can use `Func<int, int, string>`.
The `SetTitle` function has one `string` parameter more but no return type.
That would be `Action<int, int, string>`.

```cs
internal class GameObject
{
    private int nLevelWidth;
    private int nLevelHeight;

    public GameLogic()
    {
        Func<int, int, string> GetTile = (int x, int y) =>
        {
            if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
                return sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x];
            else
                return "";
        };

        Action<int, int, string> SetTile = (int x, int y, string c)=>                
        {
            if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
                sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x] = c;
        };
    }
}
```

[That´s a good article about delegates.](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-function-type-and-delegate)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and resources :)

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have correctly noted:

- You can't use `var` with a lambda in C# because the type is ambiguous. You have to state the delegate type explicitly.
- Your use of `ref` indicates that you have misunderstood how outer variable capture works in both C++ and C#. You don't need to make these `ref`, and the outer variables will be captured automatically.

However none of the answers given so far have told you the better solution to this problem, which is to not use lambdas at all!  Just use a local function.

```
public GameLogic()
{
    ... other code here ...
    string GetTile(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
            return sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x];
        else
            return "";
    }
```

No lambdas required.

Note that this solution requires C# 7.0 or higher.

(An even better solution would be to put all this code into a class; make a custom data type that does this work for you. But you asked specifically about how to port this code directly, not how to refactor it.)

Comment: Can you kindly please explain why the function that you wrote in your answer needs C# 7.0 or higher?  What is it that it's doing that is not supported with anything lower than 7.0?  Thank you and it's a pleasure to follow your daily answers!

Comment: @Zuzlx: Support for local functions was added in C# 7; lambdas were added (by me!) in C# 3, and anonymous delegates were added in C# 2; in C# 1 there was no way at all to make a function inside another. So if you are using C# 3, 4, 5 or 6, you should use a lambda to make a local function.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda Expressions doesn't have a compile time type, but is convertible to any matching delegate or expression type. That's why [according to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/implicitly-typed-lambda-expressions) lambda expressions can't be implicitly typed (also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4966409/4259962) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

So:

```cs
Func<int, int, string> GetTile = (int x, int y) =>
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
        return sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x];
    else
        return "";
};

Action<int, int, string> SetTile = (int x, int y, string c)=>                
{
   if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
       sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x] = c;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare two `delegates` like below:

```
delegate void ActionRef(ref int x, ref int y, string c);
delegate string FuncRef(ref int x, ref int y);
```

And instead of using `var`, you can these `delegates` as the type of function.

```
public GameLogic()
{
    FuncRef GetTile = (ref int x, ref int y) =>
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
            return sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x];
        else
            return "";
    };

    ActionRef SetTile = (ref int x, ref int y, string c) =>
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < nLevelWidth && y >= 0 && y < nLevelHeight)
            sLevel[y * nLevelWidth + x] = c;
    };
}
```