# Is it possible to declare and run a lambda function in an expression?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Given a very simple expression like:

```
var x = new Thing();
```

I was thinking, can you encapsulate `new Thing` as a lambda like `() => new Thing()` inline, along the lines of:

```
var x = () => new Thing();
```

This doesn't compile because I'm trying to assign a delegate to x, not the result of calling it.

But when I try:

```
var x = (() => new Thing())(); //call my lambda in-line
```

This also doesn't compile with eror "Method name expected".

So does this imply I cannot declare and use a lambda inline, or just that I don't understand the syntax?

*(Note: this is a question about understanding the language, I'm not asking if it's a good idea to do it, only if I can. My example is clearly over-simplified from any real-world use!)*

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to use a lambda. Do you want to replace the whole `GetConnection` method with a lambda? If so, I would definitely advise against that, it'll look horrible. Instead you might want to use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) but the way you extracted it is fine as well. You could also consider adding a parameter to `GetConnection` for the connection-string instead of referencing (presumably) a class variable.

Comment: I'm simply interested to know if you _can_.

Comment: Re-written. Please re-open.

Answer (score 1):

`using` gives you a boundary around `IDisposable` objects. Once you leave that boundary, the object is destroyed.

For example, take this line

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

`SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`, so once the end of the `using` block is reached, the disposal method is called.

Now let's look at your example with the lambda -

```
using (var conn = (() => new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)))
```

In this case, your variable `conn` is not a connection, instead it is an anonymous method, which of course does not implement `IDisposable`. The type of the anonymous method is dependent on the initializer expression, and you don't have one of those. More on that in a moment.

For your second example,

```
using (var conn = (() => new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))())
```

This is where I start to get confused about what you are trying to accomplish. I can't tell how you intend this to be different than

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
```

If you absolutely must do that, you would probably need to wrap it in a `Func`

```
using (var conn = new Func<SqlConnection>(() => new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)).Invoke())
```

But, again, I'm not sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: To understand the language better. I _don't_ intend it to be different .

Comment: On top of what I said, this post may help your understanding as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965576/why-cant-an-anonymous-method-be-assigned-to-var

In your inline example you are actually trying to do some implicit assignment, which is problem one.

Problem two is that parentheses have different syntactic meanings in C#, so without an explicit method name, the compiler doesn't know what it's supposed to do there. That's why you would need to use `Func<T>.Invoke()`, but that brings us back to problem one.

Comment: I've substantially rewritten and simplified this to a more abstract question. I think you have already answered it in your final code but perhaps you might edit against the revised question?